# Proper way to handle removing a member from a group in REST

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm designing a REST service which organizes groups and users.

For example:
GET /groups - gets all the groups
GET /groups/1 - gets a specific group
GET /groups/1/users - gets the users in the group
GET /users/1 - the actual user, which may be in multiple groups
POST /groups/1/users - with the post parameters of user_id=1 to add a user to a group

What would be the appropriate way to handle this?
DELETE /groups/1/users/1 seems to be a valid way to do it but then the GET to the same url would return the user record which is a duplicate of the resource /user/1?

or should it be DELETE /groups/1/users?user_id=1?

Wondering which is the most RESTful way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good design would make explicit the membership of a user within a particular group - as a separate resource. So, there are groups, users, and the membership of a user within a group.

Therefore, `GET /groups/1/users` would return a list of membership resource identifiers: `/groups/1/users/{member_id}` on which you could do a `DELETE`. Each of these "memberships" is of course associated with a particular user, so you would have to somehow know which `member_id` is associated with which `user_id`. The easiest way to do this is to make `member_id` have the same semantics as `user_id`, as you suggest in the question (so `/groups/1/users/1` means *"user 1's membership in group 1"*). Following that, if you do a GET on `/groups/1/users/{member_id}` you could just redirect to `/users/{user_id}`. Or in a more complex example, this resource would no redirect to a user but link to it and also include some other information, for example the date when the user joined the group, her status in the group, etc.

The other option I can think of would utilize the PATCH method to modify the collection resources (`/groups/1/users`): see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023. But using a DELETE seems more natural.